# The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I ran this command on the server that has the share of code that my local IIS site set to (Via UNC to that share):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320268

> `Drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe
>   -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\computername\sharename\*"
>   FullTrust -exclusive on`

(obviously I replaced Drive with C, and the actual computername and sharename with the one I'm sharing out).

But when I run the ASP.NET site, I am still getting this runtime exception:

> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the IIS service? If you didn't your change has not taken on yet.

Comment: yep that's the first thing I always try when stuff doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Have you checked the runtime policy within the **Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration** MMC? Does it reflect your change?

Answer (score 0):

First, run that command on the web server, not the file server. Second, check the account the IIS application in running as has permissions to see the file share.